# how to make a zcash rpc call using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: xmlhttprequest, rpc, zcash

I have being trying everything I can think of to get the request to work but always get connection refused.  The curl command works, but there are no examples anywhere of anything like this where you have a username and password and another flag plus the data.

Here is what I have so far

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onload = () => {
    if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {

        const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(response['result']);
    }
};

const json = { 
                "jsonrpc":"1.0",
                "method":"getbalance",
                "params":["*",1],
                "id":"1"
           };

xhr.open('POST', 'http://zfred:TXlTM2NydFBAc3N3b3Jk@127.0.0.1:8232/');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
xhr.send("--data-binary",json);
```

I have also tried  adding

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "zfred:TXlTM2NydFBAc3N3b3Jk");
xhr.withCredentials = true;
```

Nothing seems to work.  I just get connection refused.
However, this curl command works just fine.

```
curl --user zfred:TXlTM2NydFBAc3N3b3Jk --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getbalance", "params": ["*", 1] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8232/
```

Any help would be greatly appreicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the [`withCredentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) property to `true` in your `XMLHttpRequest`.